# Create usinig linq object in linst by generic Type

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics, types

I rewrote method and now we read data from .xlsx not json but I don't know how return IEnumerable .

Orginal code

```
private IEnumerable<TEntity> GetChild(string path)
    {
        var klasser = DeserializeJsonFile<IEnumerable<ParentFromJson>>(path)
            .SelectMany(parent => parent.UnderClass.Select(klasse => new TEntity
            {
                Uuid = class.Uuid,
                Name= class.Name,
                Titel = class.Titel,
                Number= class.Number,
                Manual = class.Manual,
                Parent = class.Parent
            }));

        return klasser;
    }
```

and my try

```
         var dataList = (from DataRow dr in resultTable.Rows
                                select new ParentFromJson().UnderClass.Select(x => new TEntity {

                                    Uuid = x.Uuid,
                                    Name= x.BrugervendtNoegle,
                                    Titel = x.Titel,
                                    Udgaaet = x.Udgaaet,
                                    Number= x.DisallowManual,
                                    Parent = x.Parent
                                }).FirstOrDefault());
```

Model.I don't know how put object in UnderClass list when I read from datatable

```
       private class ParentFromJson
    {
        public IEnumerable<ChildFromJson> UnderClass{ get; set; }
    }

    private class ChildFromJson
    {
        public string Uuid { get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public string Titel { get; set; }

        public bool Number{ get; set; }

        public bool Manual { get; set; }

        public string Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: *"but I don't know how return good object"* -- define good object, its unclear what you are asking

Comment: IEnumerable<TEntity>

Comment: for me, you don't need anymore ``ParentFromJson`` and ``ChildFromJson`` in your new code: but you will try code like this : ``(from DataRow dr in resultTable.Rows
select new TEntity {

 Uuid = dr["Uuid"],
 Name= dr["BrugervendtNoegle"],
 Titel = dr["Titel"],
 Udgaaet = dr["Udgaaet"],
 Number= dr["DisallowManual"],
 Parent = dr["Parent"]
});``